# Analysis: Show that this series converges, determine the limit.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

The series in question is

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{2}{n^2-1}.$$

Comment: Since it is a positive term series, you can try bounding it from above to prove convergence. For example, $\frac{2}{n^2-1}=\frac{2}{(n+1)(n-1)}\leq\frac{2}{(n+1)(n+1)}=\frac{2}{(n+1)^2}$ so the series in question is no greater than $\sum_2^\infty\frac{2}{(n+1)^2}=\sum_3^\infty\frac{2}{n^2}$ which converges.

Comment: But have you tried anything at all?

Comment: @MickG look at the answer below :)

Comment: I was seeing this from review, so I saw no answer below :). And I suspected there would be a telescopic series. Whoops :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We observe that $\frac{2}{n^2-1} = \frac{2}{(n-1)(n+1)}.$ Using partial fractions we see that $\frac{2}{(n-1)(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n+1}.$

Now we compute the $k$-th partial sum:

$$S_k=\sum_{n=2}^{k}\frac{2}{n^2-1}=\sum_{n=2}^{k}(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n+1})=1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5}+\space...\space+\frac{1}{k-1}+\frac{1}{k+1}=1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}$$

Hence

$$\sum_{n=2}^{k}\frac{2}{n^2-1}=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}S_k=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}(1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1})=1+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{2}$$